# ConfigureAwait warning in .net core 3.1

Tags: asynchronous, warnings, .net-core-3.0, configureawait, .net-core-3.1

I am developing a server in ASP NET Core 3.1 preview edition and now i see that for all my `async` methods when calling `await` i get `CA2007` warning (as it is when some task is running asynchronous).

Is there any significant change in how the way async await works in .NET Core 3.1 that i am not aware of thus i should use `ConfigureAwait`?

P.S If there is not change , is there any way for it to stop highlighting all `await`'s with green for which i am not using `configureawait` ?

Comment: There's no change and CA2007 is just an analyzer warning you can disable at the project, file or statement level. Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` can be useful in library code though, so don't rush to disable the warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specify ASP.NET Core 3.1 in your question but not what version you're coming from.  However, in ASP.NET Core (since the beginning?) you don't need to call `ConfigureAwait(false)` from ASP.NET Core.  See: [ASP.NET Core SynchronizationContext](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html) by Stephen Cleary.

To stop the warning I put this in my `GlobalSuppressions.cs`:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

[assembly: SuppressMessage("Design", "RCS1090:Call 'ConfigureAwait(false)'.", 
  Justification = "ASP.NET Core doesn't have a SynchronizationContext. https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html", 
  Scope = "NamespaceAndDescendants", 
  Target = "YourProjectNamespace.Controllers")]
```

Note the `Target = "YourProjectNamespace.Controllers"`.  I try to be specific where I suppress the warnings.  Since I can't control where my library code will be called from I want to ensure that my libraries still call `ConfigureAwait(false)`.  But in ASP.NET Core controllers I don't need to, thus the suppression.